# Javascript keeps running

Tags: javascript

I am very new to Javascript and I am having difficulty figuring out how to stop it after running first time. I have a simple refresh function and I want it to run once onLoad. Now it keep running. I would appreciate it if you can tell me how to stop it after the first run. Thank you.

```
<script>
function reload(){
   location.reload();
}
</script>
```

Comment: I'm curious, why do you want/need it to refresh in the first place?

Comment: It runs on page-load, then calls a refresh, which in turn runs this on page load.

Comment: This will create an infinite loop. You can't only run it once on page load because it will just load again, and again...

Comment: i see now how pointless this is. thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

By writing this code, you create an infinite loop:

1/First you access the page

2/then the js code is loaded, and refresh the page

3/then the js code is loaded again, and refresh the page.

4/then .......

So the page 'keep running'

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how you set refresh process but you can do something like this.

Say you got a query string and if it's set to something you wanna refresh the page e.g. `URL?refresh=1`

You can read this `refresh` value and check if it 's set to 1 . If it is redirect the page

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
  var match = RegExp('[?&]' + name + '=([^&]*)').exec(window.location.search);
  return match && decodeURIComponent(match[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}

refresh = getParameterByName("refresh");

if (refresh == "1") window.location = "URL";
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/R7Ldx/8/)**

PS: `getParameterByName` function is found in **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5158301/1906094)**